# How stable the logical expression evaluation order is? Could it be changed at compilation time of optimization?

Tags: php

I often use a code snippet like this for small transaction to keep data integrity:

```
public deleteSomething() {
    return 
        self::_tr_start() 
        && parent::delete() // deleting object itself
        && $this->deleteSomethingRelated() // deleting some related data (DB-records, files - anything)
        && self::_tr_commit() 
        || self::_tr_rollback();
}

protected static function _tr_start() {
    return Db::getInstance()->query('START TRANSACTION;');
}
protected static function _tr_commit() {
    return Db::getInstance()->query('COMMIT;');
}
protected static function _tr_rollback() {
    Db::getInstance()->query('ROLLBACK;');
    return false; // chain should return false on fail
}
```

If I sure that all methods in chain returns TRUE (on success) or FALSE (on error) - I assume than on success ALL methods EXCEPT _tr_rollback will be called (because true||something == true), and in case of error (lets say, parent::delete failed) all subsequent methods will NOT be called, BUT the _tr_rollback will be called directly after parent::delete;

So, in practice, all works exact as it expected, but I still dont sure, that it NEVER can work a different way because of some PHP-code-optimisation.

For example, could the compiler detect, that _tr_rollback always returns FALSE, and ommit it (because it will NOT affect the overall logical expression result value) ?

Or, lets say, I added a constant FALSE in "success chain" (maybe for debug purposes):

```
return
    self::_tr_start() 
    && parent::delete() 
    && $this->deleteSomethingRelated() 
    && false // CONSTANT FALSE
    && self::_tr_commit() 
    || self::_tr_rollback();
```

could the compiler ommit all except _tr_rollback at all due to some optimizations?

I really havent seen such behaviour (all code always executes as it expected), but I still not sure that it is not possible in case of some php settings.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Think PHP's "lazy evaluation", and stop doing this... it doesn't work the way you want, and that's not instability, it's your lack of understanding

Comment: why to stop? in fact,  lazy evaluation is exactly what make it work... because of this, in case of success - rollback will not be called, and in case of error - "success chain" will be interrupted... no?

Comment: In case of error, unless it's an error in the commit, then the rollback will not be called... if `parent::delete()` fails, how does that code understand that it needs to trigger the rollback? It doesn't: lazy evaluation tells it to terminate execution of that block and continue from the next line (which is exiting the method, and returning a false to the caller). The very fact that you're asking this question means you don't know whether it works or not

Comment: as I said, I use it when i *sure* that all methods in expression returns TRUE (in case of success) or FALSE( in case of error). So, if `parent::delete()` fails - it *will return FALSE*. So, logical expression bacomes like `true && false || _tr_rollback()`, and it's value if undefined untill tr_rollback() result is known, so it *must* be called to determine final expression value. No?

Comment: Why don't you do what most developers do, the more readable try/catch block; throwing exceptions if you encounter an exceptional circumstance in your code, and rollback on exception.... that's also a lot mroe readable to a majority of coders

Comment: I do a try/catch when I fully control code, but if I should just add some functionality to already existing project - I have to respect it's architecture even if I dont like it. So, often the error detecting is based on "false" return value rather then exceptions, and I prefer to keep uniform codestyle over the project for future readability. Changing overall architecture is project owner's jurisdiction.